# ssh stops working properly Solaris 11

Tags: ssh, solaris

I have a Virtual Machine in which I usually connect by ssh, and it works very good. But after a while it stops working, I can ping it, and when I ssh it, it shows the authentication screen, I enter my user, and when I put the password (I know it is the right one) it does not log in. But if I restart the server it works well again. I have no idea why is this happening. Any ideas?

*I'm not a native English speaker, in case you don't understand something, or need more information, please ask.*

Comment: The VM is a Solaris 11 zone, or...?

Comment: Also, do you get any messages after the password? No shell prompt, no motd? Connection closed? Anything in the VM's sshd logs?

Comment: It is a VM on VMware. Yes, I got a prompt with a connection closed message (Using PuTTY)

Comment: a good way to troubleshoot is for you to stop the ssh svcadm disable ssh. then run it in debug mode from the console. /usr/lib/bin/ssh -d, then connect from putty and check the messages on the server side.